# How do I get my own details for a user account?

Tags: authentication

Any way to get my own user details and not having to be an admin?

I don't get the need to be an admin to see my own user details.  (Hint to development, remove the admin required flag for a user to see their own details.)

```
Get User Details
Description: Get the details of an Artifactory user
Since: 2.4.0
Notes: Requires Artifactory Pro
Security: Requires an admin user
Usage: GET /api/security/users/{userName}
Produces: application/json (application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.security.User+json)
Sample Output:

GET /api/security/users/davids
{
user.json
}
```